# Using Liquid tags in a Jekyll page not working

Tags: ruby, git, jekyll, liquid

I am attempting to setup a small blog using Jekyll. My work so far is as follows.

- Setup a Github pages repository
- Cloned the repo locally
- Installed Ruby vs 2 and the sdk (windows)
- Installed jekyll
- 'serve' the local website.
- Validated that I could view my website localhost:4000

Everything worked fine however the liquid syntax is not working as expected. All syntax is output as plane text. I am not sure how to continue. This error happens both locally as well as on my github hosted page.

Here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
  {% include meta %}{{ site.time | date_to_xmlschema }}
</head>
<body>
  {% include header.html %}
  {% include header.html %}
  {% include header.html %}
  {% foo %}
  {{ foo }}

  <section class="main-content">
    {% include footer.html %}
  </section>
  {% include scripts.html %}
</body>
</html>
```

My _config.yml has foo defined. =(

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want Jekyll to process your page, you must add a Front matter to your page ([see dedicated page in Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)).

The minimum front matter is an empty one. That means that your page will use default configuration for layout, etc ..

```
---
# this is an empty front matter
---
Your content here
```

Comment: You can put this code block at the top of html file.

Comment: Thank you for this. The official, step-by-step Jekyll intro does not include this important detail. https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/02-liquid/

Comment: It's [on the third page of the guide](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/03-front-matter/).

Comment: ^ Not explicitly. Also, worth mentioning that the most bare-bones FrontMatter you can include is just 6 dashes with a newline between 3 and 4, no need for a comment or anything.

Comment: I landed here because of the same issue. My includes are in `_includes/` and I use `{% include navigation.html %}`. If I have a front matter they are parsed on `jekyll build`, if not, not. Jekyll is at 4.0.0! Is there a special command I have to add? like `jekyll build --also-without-front-matter`:-) ?

Comment: @Urs no front matter no proccessing.